# Can I learn the latest version of Angular.js to understand and upgrade the code written in older versions?

Tags: angularjs, angular

I know I am asking a general question and not something that is specific or something that can be reproducible through code. But I needed some clarity regarding this.

A developer in my company wrote the front end with `HTML`, `CSS`, and `Angular js (v1)`. But now I need to take over the maintenance and so I need to learn `Angular.js` too. But I found plenty of versions of `Angular.js` out there, the latest being `v6`. I also read that `v2` differs from `v1` as the developers of `Angular js` introduced `type script` in `v2` and also changed the architecture.

So I am wondering whether I need to learn `Angular js (v1)` first to understand the code and then move to `v6` and perhaps change the code base altogether.

I am sorry if the question is too general and the topic.

Comment: First of all, know that there is **Angular Js** and **Angular** - which are completely **different** frameworks. Although they are both partly developed by google.

Comment: depends on the complexity of the application, in case of complex application, you would need to know AngularJS to understand the happenings... Angular v2 (uses typescript and curent version is v7) has major differences which you would then have to learn to maintain that application...

Comment: So when you're talking about Angular Js (v1), yes that framework is actually Angular Js. But when you're talking about Angular v2 and v6, now those frameworks are known as Angular 2+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular v1 and angular v2 are different, the common reference is:

- **AngulerJS** - below angular 2 (v1)
- **Anguler** - Angular 2 and above.

---

**The difference between the two:**

Angular is based on TypeScript while AngularJS is based on JavaScript. TypeScript is a superset of ES6 and it’s backward compatible with ES5. Angular has also benefits of ES6 like: lambda operators, iterators or reflection’s mechanism.

- **AngularJS** uses terms of `$scope` and `controller`. To scope a
  variable you can add many variables that will be visible in View as
  well as in Controller. AngularJS has also a concept of rootScope.
  Variables in rootScope are available on all throughout application.
- **Angular** does not have a concept of scope or controllers. Instead of
  them it uses a hierarchy of components as its main architectural
  concept. Component is a directive with a template. That is a similar
  approach as in ReactJS – another library used for building user
  interfaces.
- **AngularJS** has many directives and every developer can also specify
  custom new directive. Angular also has standard directives, but they
  are used in a bit different way. For example: ng-model in AngularJS
  means that you want to create two-way binding. If you want to create
  one-way binding, you should use ng-bind. Angular occurs only ngModel,
  but if you would write it only in: `[ ]`, you’ll get one-way binding.
  If you want to create two-way binding you must write it in: `[( )]`.
  We have to write it this way because of the fact that “[ ]” is used
  to property binding and `( )` is used to event binding.
- **In Angular**, some directives have changed their names like ng-repeat
  to ngFor - *This is mainly a semantic change rather then logical functionality change*.
- **Angular** has couple of more changes from the old version.

  - The    first is modularity. Much core functionality was moved to
    different    modules. That caused lighter and faster core, dynamic
    loading,    asynchronous template compilation and added support for
    reactive    programming. After beta version creators added really
    great thing:    angular cli. With that package you can easily create
    scaffolding of    your Angular project which will be all configured.

As you can see, the major difference between **AngularJS** and **Angular** is the change of concept between `controller` and `component`.
While in *AngularJS* you had a controller and you could `$scope` variables in that controller and even define custom directives, in angular the component is a directive with a template and there is also a hierarchy of components.

Comment: Hey thanks for bringing in some clarity and helping me understand the difference. +1 for your answer.